# z-test for groups in the df, but comparing all groups to just one other group?

Tags: r, group-by, statistics, z-score

I am trying to generate z scores (then pvalues) by group, by only changing one of the groups each time, ie comparing each group to another 'reference' group, with the idea that I can do hypothesis testing to see if they are distinct distributions.

In the below example, I would like to perform z-tests on a, b and c, all against d:

z-test comparing a vs d,

z-test comparing b vs d

z-test comparing c vs d

```
> df
group measurement 
a     1
a     2
b     6
b     7
b     9
c     4
c     5
c     4
d     8
d     8
```

so that my end df looks something like this:

```
> group_df 
group pvalue
a     0.005
b     0.3
c     0.001
d     1.000
```

So far I have something like this:

```
# d group stats
d_only <- df %>% filter(grepl("d", group)) %>% select("measurement")
d_mean <- mean(admeasurement)
d_n    <- nrow(d_only)


# generate values needed to calculate zscore 
group_df <- df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean, sd, n()))
group_df$sqrt_n   <- (group_df$n + d_n) %>% sqrt()
group_df$pop_mean <- (group_df$mean + d_mean) / 2


# calculate zscore
group_df $zscore <- 
(group_df$mean - group_df$pop_mean) / (group_df$sd / group_df$sqrt_n)

 
group_df$pvalue <- pnorm(-abs(zscore))
```

But I am getting some p values that seem wrong, and it fees like there should be a more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: Maybe you want to try the `pairwise.t.test()` function.

Comment: Using z-scores does not make sense for comparing two distributions because you are standardizing each distribution to mean=0 and sd=1.  That essentially eliminates the differences between them. If you do want to compute z-scores, why not just use the function `score()`?